# How to cancel restore command in Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

When the [RESTORE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-get-started-restore) command is executed on Azure SQL Database Managed Instance it cannot be stopped because this is executed asynchronously:

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE wwidb FROM URL =
  'https://mitutorials.blob.core.windows.net/databases/WideWorldImporters-Standard.bak'
```

How can we cancel this request? The database is in the restoring state (sometime shown with GUID name) and cannot be dropped. The request cannot be canceled until it finishes.

Answer (score 3):

During restore, the database is registered in Managed Instance using their physical name. Once restore finishes, physical name will be replaced with the name placed in the RESTORE command.

The only way to cancel the request is to drop the database via [Azure CLI](https://medium.com/azure-sqldb-managed-instance/working-with-sql-managed-instance-using-azure-cli-611795fe0b44) or [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/az.sql/remove-azsqlinstancedatabase?view=azps-2.6.0#examples) using the name specified in the RESTORE command:

Azure CLI:

```
az sql midb delete -g my_resource_group --mi myInstance --name wwi
```

Azure PowerShell

```
Remove-AzSqlInstanceDatabase -Name "wwi" -InstanceName myInstance1 -ResourceGroupName my_resource_group
```

Comment: Another way seems to be by killing the other SPID (the one with ApplicationName="RestoreService"), which is running the RESTORE command internally.